# Using groupby and apply to add column to each group

Tags: python, pandas, transform, apply

I have a DataFrame with a multi-index as a column. I want to group by level 1 and apply a function that generates a new column. I want this calculated column to be added to each group, and thus my dataframe to have new columns for each group.

I made a little dummy script and function to replicate what I want to do.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = [('A','julian'),('A','geoffrey'),
       ('B','julian'),('B','geoffrey'),
       ('C','julian'),('C','geoffrey')]

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,6),columns=columns)

def addColumn(inputDF):
   group = inputDF.columns[0][1]
   inputDF['sum', group] = inputDF.sum(axis=1)
   return inputDF

newColumnsDataframe = dataframe.groupby(level=1, axis=1).apply(addColumn)
```

The original dataframe looks as follows:

```
      A                   B                   C          
    julian  geoffrey    julian  geoffrey    julian  geoffrey
 0  0.204082  0.073676  0.795725  0.279702  0.258185  0.258112
 1  0.263235  0.096733  0.507324  0.541198  0.525919  0.757652
 2  0.196243  0.028613  0.653408  0.364365  0.174911  0.924733
 3  0.528785  0.831569  0.654160  0.738029  0.940831  0.294473
 4  0.853517  0.263250  0.803087  0.855270  0.701937  0.264698
 5  0.239797  0.069519  0.943544  0.374411  0.189361  0.846647
 6  0.980734  0.290414  0.850097  0.873785  0.903645  0.118713
 7  0.591942  0.088387  0.566298  0.062140  0.568482  0.872064
 8  0.818167  0.061483  0.282050  0.008404  0.449198  0.658370
 9  0.217424  0.427602  0.471933  0.171458  0.390549  0.234426
```

The resulting dataframe should look as follows (I constructed the sum DataFrame separately and concatenated the two dataframes to achieve this results):

```
      A         B         C       sum         A         B         C  \
   geoffrey  geoffrey  geoffrey  geoffrey    julian    julian    julian   
0  0.073676  0.279702  0.258112  0.611491  0.204082  0.795725  0.258185   
1  0.096733  0.541198  0.757652  1.395584  0.263235  0.507324  0.525919   
2  0.028613  0.364365  0.924733  1.317710  0.196243  0.653408  0.174911   
3  0.831569  0.738029  0.294473  1.864071  0.528785  0.654160  0.940831   
4  0.263250  0.855270  0.264698  1.383219  0.853517  0.803087  0.701937   
5  0.069519  0.374411  0.846647  1.290578  0.239797  0.943544  0.189361   
6  0.290414  0.873785  0.118713  1.282912  0.980734  0.850097  0.903645   
7  0.088387  0.062140  0.872064  1.022590  0.591942  0.566298  0.568482   
8  0.061483  0.008404  0.658370  0.728257  0.818167  0.282050  0.449198   
9  0.427602  0.171458  0.234426  0.833486  0.217424  0.471933  0.390549   

    sum  
   julian  
0  1.257992  
1  1.296478  
2  1.024561  
3  2.123776  
4  2.358542  
5  1.372703  
6  2.734476  
7  1.726721  
8  1.549415  
9  1.079906
```

The approach in the script above is based on what makes sense to me and what others have written online about doing this sort of thing. However, newColumnsDataframe still only has 6 columns, not 8 (one added for each name).

I did notice that when I group by level=0 (so by A, B, or C) and use transform(but NOT when I use apply on this level), newColumnsDataframe does have 9 columns, one sum column added for each group. See the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = [('A','julian'),('A','geoffrey'),
       ('B','julian'),('B','geoffrey'),
       ('C','julian'),('C','geoffrey')]

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,6),columns=columns)

def addColumn(inputDF):
    group = inputDF.columns[0][1]
    inputDF[group, 'sum'] = inputDF.sum(axis=1)
    return inputDF

newColumnsDataframe = dataframe.groupby(level=0, axis=1).transform(addColumn)
```

It was always my understanding that transform worked on each column within the group, whereas apply operated on the group as a whole dataframe. This seems to contradict that. 
I also noticed, that when I group by level=1 and use transform in stead of apply, it throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 10 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

I am very confused about what is going on. Does anyone know why this DOES work when I use transform and group on level=0. Why there is an error when I do the same but group on level=1. And why grouping on EITHER level and APPLYING the function does not add columns to my final dataframe? Thanks in advance!

(PS: This is not the actual DataFrame or function I am using to add a column, just an easier illustration)

Comment: Could you add an desired output?

Comment: It bears repeating. What is your intended end result? Interesting question, good roadmap, but no destination.

Comment: I just added the original dataframe and the desired result. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of messy, but a one-liner:

```
(df.join(pd.concat({'sum': df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()}, axis=1))
   .sortlevel(level=1, axis=1))
```

Produces this for me:

```
          A         B         C       sum         A         B         C  \
   geoffrey  geoffrey  geoffrey  geoffrey    julian    julian    julian   
0  0.073676  0.279702  0.258112  0.611490  0.204082  0.795725  0.258185   
1  0.096733  0.541198  0.757652  1.395583  0.263235  0.507324  0.525919   
2  0.028613  0.364365  0.924733  1.317711  0.196243  0.653408  0.174911   
3  0.831569  0.738029  0.294473  1.864071  0.528785  0.654160  0.940831   
4  0.263250  0.855270  0.264698  1.383218  0.853517  0.803087  0.701937   
5  0.069519  0.374411  0.846647  1.290577  0.239797  0.943544  0.189361   
6  0.290414  0.873785  0.118713  1.282912  0.980734  0.850097  0.903645   
7  0.088387  0.062140  0.872064  1.022591  0.591942  0.566298  0.568482   
8  0.061483  0.008404  0.658370  0.728257  0.818167  0.282050  0.449198   
9  0.427602  0.171458  0.234426  0.833486  0.217424  0.471933  0.390549   

        sum  
     julian  
0  1.257992  
1  1.296478  
2  1.024562  
3  2.123776  
4  2.358541  
5  1.372702  
6  2.734476  
7  1.726722  
8  1.549415  
9  1.079906
```

I just said "here's my `df`, lets first group by the names of the people and sum it, then join these two summed columns back to the original `df`, then use `sortlevel` to sort by `level=1` and `axis=1`."

So, the only reason 'sum' is appearing after `C` column is only because the letter `s` comes after `C`.  If you had a column named `x`, this wouldn't work.  Not sure if that matters though.

Here's the `df` I used for recreation-purposes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
      ('C', 'julian'): [0.258185, 0.52591899999999991, 0.17491099999999998, 0.94083099999999997, 0.70193700000000003, 0.189361, 0.90364500000000003, 0.56848199999999993, 0.44919799999999993, 0.39054899999999998],
      ('B', 'geoffrey'): [0.27970200000000001, 0.54119799999999996, 0.36436499999999999, 0.73802900000000005, 0.85527000000000009, 0.37441099999999999, 0.87378500000000003, 0.062140000000000001, 0.008404, 0.171458], 
      ('A', 'julian'): [0.20408199999999999, 0.263235, 0.196243, 0.52878500000000006, 0.85351699999999997, 0.23979699999999998, 0.98073399999999999, 0.59194199999999997, 0.81816699999999998, 0.21742399999999998], 
      ('B', 'julian'): [0.79572500000000002, 0.507324, 0.65340799999999999, 0.65416000000000007, 0.803087, 0.94354400000000005, 0.85009699999999988, 0.56629799999999997, 0.28205000000000002, 0.47193299999999999], 
      ('A', 'geoffrey'): [0.073676000000000005, 0.096733, 0.028613, 0.831569, 0.26324999999999998, 0.069519000000000011, 0.29041400000000001, 0.088387000000000007, 0.061483000000000003, 0.42760200000000004], 
      ('C', 'geoffrey'): [0.25811200000000001, 0.75765199999999999, 0.92473300000000003, 0.29447299999999998, 0.26469799999999999, 0.84664699999999993, 0.11871300000000001, 0.87206399999999995, 0.65837000000000001, 0.23442600000000002]},
      columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A','julian'),('A','geoffrey'), ('B','julian'),('B','geoffrey'), ('C','julian'),('C','geoffrey')]))
```

**Edited:**

Here's another approach:

```
sum_columns = [('sum', name) for name in df.columns.levels[1].tolist()]
df[sum_columns] = df.groupby(axis=1, level=1).sum()
df = df.sortlevel(level=1, axis=1)
```

`sum_columns` - looks like this `[('sum', 'geoffrey'), ('sum', 'julian')]`.

`df[sum_columns]` creates a new 'sum' column for each name on level 1.

If it's desired to have the sum column next to the name, use `sortlevel`.

Comment: That was a neat one!

Comment: Awesome! I think this would work (The actual function and dataframe are more complicated but do not see why this would not transfer). Thanks so much. Do you know why the apply did not work though? Still trying to wrap my head around that

Comment: One thought I had was that in your function `group = inputDF.columns[0][1]` returns the string `'julian'`. Since you're applying a function to a DataFrameGroupBy object with multiple groups ('julian', 'geoffrey'), maybe it doesn't know hat to do for geoffrey? I could be way wrong about this.  `addColumn(dataframe)` does return a `(sum, julian)` column but the sums in that column are the sum of both julian and geoffrey for each row. I think you want the sum by person so your function might need changing.

Comment: I see. The column it returns should be a sum only of the person right? Because I group by person (level=1) and then apply the function to each group? Or is it not true that .apply causes the function to be applied to each group as a dataframe? (Your answer worked in my actual code by the way. Thank you for the help!)

Comment: You make very good points. I don't know (and it's bothering me) because I went through your function and see it does what I'd expect.  If I figure this out, I'll let you know!